# How can you unlock Cyrus in Animal Crossing New Leaf

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

How can you unlock Cyrus in Animal Crossing New Leaf? I don't know how to unlock Cyrus.

Answer (score 2):

In order to unlock Cyrus, you need to fulfill the following conditions

- 100,000 Bells worth of items have been sold to Reese.
- 50 pieces of furniture have been cataloged (found at the Nookling Stores).
- 10 pieces of clothing cataloged (from the Able Sisters).
- The player has played for seven days.

Note: cataloged means - owned at one point.

Source: [Animal Crossing Wiki](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Cyrus)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do the "10 pieces of clothing" _have_ to be bought _in_ the Able Sisters' shop, or can they be acquired elsewhere (e.g. trading with friend) and only need to be something that you _could_ purchase in their store?

Comment: Good question. I haven't found anything stating something specific yet, but it seems that every piece of clothing counts.